# Ink Filepicker.io how to cancel upload in progress

Tags: filepicker.io

I am using the filepicker.io and the pickAndStore() method. Is there a way to put a cancel button on the modal so that the user can stop the upload in progress? It appears that the "x" in the upper right does that, but I think a button would be more intuitive to my users.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ink File Picker engineer here.

There isn't a way besides the 'x' button in the upper right to do that at the moment. I'll be sure to filter this feedback to the product team and note that it's not clear to users how to cancel and we'll look into ways on how to make that better.